# how to convert LibSVM file with multi classes into an RDD[labelPoint]

Tags: apache-spark, libsvm, apache-spark-mllib

using the following method from org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils package ,Loads binary labeled data in the LIBSVM format into an RDD[LabeledPoint], with number of features determined automatically and the default number of partitions.

```
def loadLibSVMFile(sc: SparkContext, path: String): RDD[LabeledPoint]
```

My problem is with loading data with multi class labels?
When using this method on multiclass labeled data...it is getting converted to binary labeled data..
is there a way to load multiclass data in LibSVM format into an RDD[LabeledPoint]...??

there is one more method in the same package with the following description

Loads labeled data in the LIBSVM format into an RDD[LabeledPoint], with the default number of partitions.

```
def loadLibSVMFile(sc: SparkContext, path: String, numFeatures: Int): RDD[LabeledPoint]
```

but when i'm trying to use this ,,there is an error showing "found Int ,requires Boolean"

Answer (score 0):

What version of Spark are you using? I just used this file
http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/multiclass/glass.scale

Spark 1.1 and the following code:

```
val lbldRDD = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc,svmFile)
lbldRDD.map(_.label).collect().toSet.map(println)
```

I see output:

5.0
1.0
6.0
2.0
7.0
3.0

which seems correct to me